# Lazy Loading. Both entities managed?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, lazy-loading

I have a simple question. I know that lazy loading beans, that the partner entity in the realtion will be loaded when needed. That only works when the entity that "has" the other entity is managed.

My friend said: The partner entity has to be managed too!

My question: Do both entities in a relation need to be managed for lazy loading, or just the owner of the relationship?

Answer (score 0):

If something is loaded lazily, then it must be a proxy created by Hibernate. So, basically, the answer is:

Yes, the proxy has to be managed by Hibernate.

However, if byte code instrumentation is used, then Hibernate may even not create the proxy, because it can intercept the code that accesses the lazily loaded entity. In that case, if the lazily loaded entity is not accessed, then there will be neither real entity nor proxy. Of course, once the entity is accessed and loaded, it will be managed by Hibernate like any other entity instance in the persistence context (session).

Answer (score 0):

The anwer is inside your question: a lazy relationship mean that hibernate know that maybe will be entities on the other side, but didn't know which, so how can be managed a non existent entity? Neither the proxy is a managed entity but just a kind of listener.